# I need help making a non realistic spider web so I can 3D print tokens for a game

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image]

So I have this and need it to look like a cartoon spiderweb so I need to inverse each of the curves and I'm not sure how to. I'm very new to 3D modeling and blender.

I'd like it to look like this [image]

Comment: will this be embossed/relief on a disk, or a filigree, as shown?

Comment: It will be relief on a disk

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Proportionnal Editing Tool for that. It's a tool that allow to move only certain vertices, but the surounding vertices are kinda attracted to them.

Select your ring and enter Edit mode (Tab). Select the vertices near every intersection. You can use the Circle select ("C") to do it easily.
[image: step 1]

Press the "O" key to activate the PET, and select a type of interpolation in this list (Sharp should give good results) 
[image: step 2]

Now scale the vertices up with the "S" key. **While you are scaling**, you can adjust the effect radius of the PET whith the mouse wheel.

[image: result]